# ¿Cómo crear una función en R que replique los promedios de dos celdas?

Tags: r, date, script, función-personalizada, celdas

Tengo la siguiente base de datos: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta BD tiene 12 columnas, año, DoY (día), Hour (hora) y nueve variables más. El año es el mismo en toda la BD (por lo que no es relevante); la columna DoY se refiere a los 366 (año bisiesto) días del año; la columna Hour se refiere a las horas de cada día y los datos están por cada media hora, es decir 0 y 0.5 corresponden a las 12:00 horas, 1 y 1.5 corresponden a la 1:00 am y así sucesivamente, en total tengo 48 datos por día * 366 días. El problema: para cada variable necesito obtener el promedio de cada hora, es decir necesito los promedios de las horas 0 y 0.5, de la 1 y 1.5, de las 2 y 2.5, etc. de tal manera que por día ya no tenga 48 datos, sino 24. Esto lo necesito para cada día del año, es decir hacerlo 366 veces. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Los -9999 son NA, por lo que se omiten en la operación. Quisiera crear un código en R para futuras réplicas de los datos.

Agradezco su orientación y consejos.

Comment: Hola, por lo que entiendo, entonces, conceptualmente tu variable de hora sería de tipo categórica aunque tenga valores numéricos. Crea una nueva variable factor o de texto para tus 24 horas y luego puedes revisar la ayuda de la función `aggregate()` para que apliques la función `mean()` al resto de variables por tu variable categórica de interés, en este caso las horas del día. Sería más fácil proponerte el código si hicieras disponible un fragmento de tu base de datos en formato replicable.

Comment: Bienvenida  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

El "quid" del problema es como "juntar" los valores de Hora de a dos como lo has indicado, y lo más fácil, se me ocurre es usar la función `floor()`, ejemplo:

```
floor(c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5))
[1] 0 0 1 1
```

Con esto, lo que resta es simplemente agrupar y sumarizar con `mean()`. Lo puedes hacer con R base:

```
aggregate(cbind(DoY, Hora=floor(Hour)) ~ NEE + LE, df, mean)
```

`df`, viene a ser tus datos, la formula expresa las variables a agrupar y las variables a sumarizar, resta que agregues el nombre de todas las variables (yo solo indique dos a modo de ejemplo).

Otra posibilidad es usar `tidyverse`, pero el procedimiento es básicamente el mismo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(DoY, Hora = floor(Hour)) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("NEE", "LE"), mean)
```

Comment: Patricio, muchas gracias, voy a intentar con tus sugerencias. =)